# How to fix my Repository creation on spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

For personal reasons I have multiple repositories for the same entity where I have multiple native named queries that I need, my first idea was to move the queries code from entity to repository so when I want to edit a query I will find it in the repository not the entity (to avoid a big entity code full of queries).

So I tried this implementation.

This My repository:

```
@SqlResultSetMappings({ @SqlResultSetMapping(name = TypeProduitRepository.REPOSITORY_SELECT_MAPPING, columns = {
        @ColumnResult(name = "code", type = Long.class), @ColumnResult(name = "description", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "valeur_decimal", type = Double.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "valeur_entier", type = Long.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "valeur_alpha_num", type = String.class) }) })

@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = TypeProduitRepository.REPOSITORY + ".select",
                query = 
                "SELECT "
                + "rp.parcin AS code,"
                + "rp.pardesc AS description, "
                + "rp.parvald AS valeur_decimal,"
                + "rp.parvall AS valeur_entier, "
                + "rp.parvals AS valeur_alpha_num\r\n"
                + "FROM ref_param rp\r\n" 
                + "WHERE rp.partab = "+TypeProduitRepository.TABLE_CODE+" AND rp.donord = \"mds\";",
                resultSetMapping = TypeProduitRepository.REPOSITORY_SELECT_MAPPING),

        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = TypeProduitRepository.REPOSITORY + ".insert",
                query =
                "INSERT INTO `ref_param` "
                + "( `partab`, `derprg`, `deruser`, `donord`, `indicmaj`, `indtrans`, `pardesc`, `parvald`, `parvall`, `parvals`)"
                + " VALUES " + "( "+TypeProduitRepository.TABLE_CODE+", :derprg, :deruser, :donord, 0, 0, :pardesc, :parvald, :parvall, :parvals);"
                + "\r\n" + ""),

        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = TypeProduitRepository.REPOSITORY + ".update", 
                query = 
                "UPDATE ref_param \r\n" 
                + "SET \r\n" 
                + " datmaj = NOW() -- datmaj - DATE NOT NULL\r\n"
                + " ,derprg = :derprg -- derprg - VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL\r\n"
                + " ,deruser = :deruser -- deruser - VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL\r\n"
                + " ,donord = :donord -- donord - VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL\r\n"
                + " ,indicmaj = indicmaj+1 -- indicmaj - BIGINT(20)\r\n"
                + " ,pardesc = :pardesc -- pardesc - VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL\r\n"
                + " ,parvald = :parvald -- parvald - DOUBLE\r\n" 
                + " ,parvall = :parvall -- parvall - BIGINT(20)\r\n"
                + " ,parvals = :parvals -- parvals - VARCHAR(255)\r\n" 
                + "WHERE\r\n"
                + "  parcin = :parcin -- parcin - BIGINT(20) NOT NULL\r\n"
                + "  AND partab = "+TypeProduitRepository.TABLE_CODE+" -- partab - BIGINT(20) NOT NULL\r\n ;" ),

        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = TypeProduitRepository.REPOSITORY + ".incerementInd", 
                query = 
                "UPDATE ref_param \r\n" 
                + "SET \r\n" 
                + " indtrans = indtrans+1 -- datmaj - DATE NOT NULL\r\n"
                + "WHERE\r\n"
                + "  parcin = :parcin -- parcin - BIGINT(20) NOT NULL\r\n"
                + "  AND partab = "+TypeProduitRepository.TABLE_CODE+" -- partab - BIGINT(20) NOT NULL\r\n ;" ),

        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name =TypeProduitRepository.REPOSITORY + ".delete",
                query=
                "DELETE FROM pos_auth.ref_param\r\n" + 
                "WHERE\r\n" + 
                "  parcin = :parcin  -- parcin - BIGINT(20) NOT NULL\r\n" + 
                "  AND partab = "+TypeProduitRepository.TABLE_CODE+" -- partab - BIGINT(20) NOT NULL"
                )

})

@Repository
public interface TypeProduitRepository extends JpaRepository<ReferencielParamettre, ReferencielParamettreID> {

    public static final String REPOSITORY = "ReferencielParamettre.TypeProduitRepository";
    public static final String REPOSITORY_SELECT_MAPPING = "ReferencielParamettre.TypeProduit";
    public static final String TABLE_CODE = "1004";

    @Query(name =REPOSITORY+".select" ,nativeQuery = true)
    public List<TypeProduit> select();

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(name =REPOSITORY+".insert" ,nativeQuery = true)
    public int insert( String derprg, String deruser, String donord, String pardesc, Double parvald, Long parvall, String parvals);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(name =REPOSITORY+".update" ,nativeQuery = true)
    public int update(Long parcin, String derprg, String deruser, String donord, String pardesc,    Double parvald, Long parvall, String parvals);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(name =REPOSITORY+".incerementInd" ,nativeQuery = true)
    public int incerementInd(Long parcin);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(name =REPOSITORY+".delete" ,nativeQuery = true)
    public int delete(Long parcin);

}
```

Next here is my entity:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "REF_PARAM")
@IdClass(ReferencielParamettreID.class)
@Check(constraints = "PARVALS IS NOT NULL OR PARVALD IS NOT NULL OR PARVALL IS NOT NULL ")
public class ReferencielParamettre extends CommonData implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7744229498316267737L;

    /**
     * partab Number code interne table parametre X N 1080 table de unite de mesure
     */
    @Id
    private Long partab;

    /**
     * parcin Number code interne parametre X N code 1 pour CM
     */
    @Id
    private Long parcin;

    /**
     * pardesc Varchar description du parametre X N par exemple : cm, centimetre
     * affichage
     */
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String pardesc;

    /**
     * parvall Number valeur entiere du parametre X Y par exemple coeficiant dual en
     * mode affichage devrai avoir la valeur 2
     */
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Long parvall;

    /**
     * parvald Number(5.2) valeur flotante du parametre X N par exemple Pi en
     * affichage vaux 3.14
     */
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Double parvald;

    /**
     * parvals VARCHAR valeur charactere du parametre X N par exemple pme vaux
     * petite moyenne entreprise: possible utile dans l'impression d'une facture
     */
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String parvals;

}
```

When launching I do get the following exception :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeProduitRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract int mds.ref.common.repository.TypeProduitRepository.update(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)! No property update found for type ReferencielParamettre!

here is the full stack trace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeProduitRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract int mds.ref.common.repository.TypeProduitRepository.update(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)! No property update found for type ReferencielParamettre!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at mds.ResourceApplication.main(ResourceApplication.java:28) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeProduitRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract int mds.ref.common.repository.TypeProduitRepository.update(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)! No property update found for type ReferencielParamettre!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeProduitRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract int mds.ref.common.repository.TypeProduitRepository.update(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)! No property update found for type ReferencielParamettre!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:392) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:364) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2afbee97.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:604) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:524) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:566) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:467) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2afbee97.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$6(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2afbee97$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1ba8ac87.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2afbee97.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeProduitRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract int mds.ref.common.repository.TypeProduitRepository.update(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)! No property update found for type ReferencielParamettre!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'typeProduitRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract int mds.ref.common.repository.TypeProduitRepository.update(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)! No property update found for type ReferencielParamettre!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1095) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:89) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter.setApplicationContext(DomainClassConverter.java:109) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration.addFormatters(SpringDataWebConfiguration.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addFormatters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addFormatters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:78) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.mvcConversionService(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:495) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2afbee97.CGLIB$mvcConversionService$8(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2afbee97$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1ba8ac87.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2afbee97.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract int mds.ref.common.repository.TypeProduitRepository.update(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)! No property update found for type ReferencielParamettre!
```

Comment: resultmapping and the likes are only available for entities or entity packages NOT on any arbitrary objects.

Comment: ok!, is there any workaround like adding some scan annotation !! or there is a better way to avoid a full entity of sql queries !!! @M.Deinum

Comment: No as it has to be part of the stuff that JPA reads. The repositories aren't read by JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mentioned In the comments by M.Deinum

> resultmapping and the likes are only available for entities or entity packages NOT on any arbitrary objects.

there is no way if it is not in an entity